# How can I select a Frame Element on a website?

Tags: javascript

I would like to run the following Code on a Website:

```
document.getElementById("FileLeafRef_8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8_$onetidIOFile").value = "test";
```

The Problem is that I have to choose the Frame "EditForm.aspx":

In the IE I can easily choose the Frame by manually clicking on it, but I would like to do it only in JavaScript, without a Manual select.

I tried it with a

```
parent.frame[x]
```

But I think this is the wrong path...

Comment: It might help if we could see your HTML

Comment: @Gina Hi! I think that this question can be easily answered through a quick google. Please try
https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+programmatically+target+iframe
The question should either be much more specific or include more code so someone can answer it.